# Is there a good tool to look into a dll library so far?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineer

Which tool would you recommend?

Comment: you should retag or post what you OS system is (I'm assuming Windows but a version would be helpful)

Comment: the answer depends entirely on what you want to look at. i mean: 'hexeditor' is a valid answer right now too.

Answer (score 5):

For native DLLs the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool will show you all of the exported functions as well as id numbers and address for each function.  It will also list the DLLs that the DLL directly depends on.

If you are looking at a .NET/Managed DLL check out [Red Gate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  It will completely disassemble the DLL and show you the code in the .NET language of your choice.  An excellent tool!

Comment: I'm not targeting .Net and dependency walker can't show the details of functions.

Comment: What specific details are you looking for?  Is the DLL you're looking at one you built or one from a 3rd party?

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never done it before, but here's what i found online to try:

> - [Peek](http://members.ping.at/mlubich)
> - [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/)
> - [Resource Editor](http://www.restuner.com/howto-openfile.htm)

[This](http://filext.com/faq/look_into_files.php) lists a few more as well.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried Resource Editor but it can't give the details of methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targetting native code, you're looking for a disassembler/decompiler. Good luck, hope you can read assembly. As far as I know there's no other way from just a normally compiled and optimized native .dll.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembly

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler